# Clojure.spec "or" equivalent of "s/and"

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I've enjoyed working with `clojure.spec`; it has helped uncover data errors closer to the cause. Currently I am using it to validate a response to a web server request, but I am having difficulty with the syntax for the clojure.spec operation that would allow two different map structure responses.

In my data, there are two possible responses from the web server request:

`{:assignment "1232123"}` and

`{:no-more-assignments true}`

I could use `multi-spec`, but that seems verbose for something that could be as simple as having one spec for each case and defining the spec as:

```
(s/def ::response
  (s/or ::case-1 ::case-2))
```

Is there some syntax that I am overlooking or will I need to use `multi-spec`?

Comment: Why can't you use `or`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `or` and `and` with `keys` specs:

```
(s/def ::assignment string?)
(s/def ::no-more-assignments boolean?)
(s/def ::response
  (s/keys :req-un [(or ::assignment ::no-more-assignments)]))

(s/explain ::response {:assignment "123"})
;; Success!
(s/explain ::response {:foo true})
;; val: {:foo true} fails spec: :sandbox.so/response predicate: (or (contains? % :assignment) (contains? % :no-more-assignments))
```

Comment: That works! Thank. What if the ::asignment was a map instead of a string? It fails when I define:
(s/def ::assignment (s/keys :req-un [::id ::reason]))

Comment: @frank I'm not sure what's going on but this should work regardless of what the `::assignment` spec is. Can you detail how it's failing now?